# Magento 2 URL rewrite appending .html.html

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, url-rewrite, html, magento2-migration-tool

I've migrated my store from version 1.9 to 2.1.1 using a tool.

However all the old products are appending html.html at the end of the URL. I basically truncate the url_rewrite table and saved all the categories. That created new URLs.

It looked good for few days, but now slowly I am noticing that some URLs are changing again to html.html.

This is not good for any business. It looks like when I create a new category or edit an existing category, all the products are being affected.

The new products entered into 2.1.1 are not affected by this bug — only the old ones I migrated from 1.9.

Comment: Hi @roger, what tool do you used, can you provide and example of the Urls being affected? You can replace the domain name to keep it private if you want.

Comment: https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-tool/

Answer (score 1):

The thing is your product's `url_key` and `url_path` have `.html` in them.

Here is what I did to get rid of that problem.

**Warning:** If your links have been having `.html.html` for some time they've probably already got indexed by google. To avoid loosing any traffic make sure you redirect `.html.html` to `.html` with your web server after you apply my fix.

Login to your DB and issue the following commands:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar
 SET value=replace(value,'.html','') WHERE attribute_id IN
  (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute
    WHERE attribute_code in ('url_key','url_path') AND entity_type_id =
     (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE 
      entity_type_code='catalog_product'));

DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE target_path LIKE "%.html.html%";

UPDATE IGNORE url_rewrite SET request_path = REPLACE(request_path, '.html.html', '.html');
```

Then reindex the database:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

And the issue should be fixed.